# python how to find exact match of a number in a string

Tags: python

How do you match an integer inside a list of strings?

My code looks like:

```
test_number = 123 # some number 1-399
lst = ["XXXXXXX-123_xxxxxxx",
       "XXXXXXX-399_xxxxxxx", ...]
# lst[0] should match, lst[1] should not
```

What I need to do is if the `test_number` appears in any of the strings in `lst`, I need to perform an operation on the string.

Do I use `re.search`? But `search` compare strings, and my test_number is integer.

Comment: OP: I've edited your post to attempt to clarify the question without adding any additional information. Can you confirm that I've correctly interpreted your question, or roll back the edit and clarify yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
test_number = 123
str1="XXjdasjXX-123_dsajdfs"
x= re.search("{}".format(test_number),str1).group()
print (x)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
123
>>>
```

Used `search` to find a match and `format` to place our number. And `group()` to convert it to str from `object`.

If you want to use that as an integer, before printing it, add `x=int(x)` then converted it to integer!

Comment: beware that this also matches `str1=XX123sjXX-999_dsajdfs`

Comment: His example is not like that, only contains a number.

Comment: His example lists unknowns for everything before the `-` and after the `_`. It's entirely reasonable to assume there may be a false positive where the test number matches other places in the string. Note also that your code is equivalent to `str(test_number) in str1`, but much slower :(. You also don't account for the fact that `str1` is supposed to be a list of strings. *Ugh* :(

Answer (score 3):

If you know it will be formatted exactly that way, try this rather than regex:

```
test_number = 307

your_list = ["ABC109$-307_letters##", "XYZ876%-100_numbers!"]

for value in your_list:
    if "-" + str(test_number) + "_" in value:
    # equivalently: "-{}_".format(str(test_number))
        # do something with that value
```

However if you're NOT sure that immediately surrounding your target values will be `-` and `_`, you should use a regex. Unfortunately in that case it's really hard to tell what your pattern should be, since I wouldn't know that edge case.

Comment: Your test is subject to false positives as well.  if `value=-307_XXX-2-xxxxxxxx`, your test will match, when it shouldn't.

Comment: It seemed unlikely enough that the noise would "sound" like `-###_` that I didn't bother worrying about it, but it is possible, yes! :) Unfortunately it's impossible to guess what the formatting will be of OP's data

Answer (score 1):

Using same assumption as Adam Smith (your string will be formatted EXACTLY like that), you should just strip off the beginning and ending of your strings before searching for your number:

```
test_number = 123
for elem in your_list:
    if str(test_number) == elem[8:-8]:
        # match - do something
```

Comment: Is string slicing faster than string composition and membership testing? I could imagine this being marginally safer in case some of the "noise" *sounds* like `-###_` but...

Comment: @AdamSmith:  I haven't tested, but I'm pretty sure it is considerably faster (but only with much, much larger test cases).  Any speed difference would be negligible in this test.

Comment: `timeit` agrees with you, saving 4ms over 1,000,000 runs :)

Comment: @AdamSmith:  You beat me to it (no point in completing my test now)!

Comment: @AdamSmith:  Finished my test anyway...this method isn't `considerably faster` at all.  Even with much larger test cases it's only marginally faster (maybe 10%).  I think the reason is that Python's compiler basically turns your string concatenation into a constant (since it never changes), so doesn't have to re-evaluate it every time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like.

```
def checkInt(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

test_num = 123
x = "XXXX-123_xxx"
y = x.split("-")
z = y[1].split("_")
if checkInt(z[0]) == True:
    num = int(z[0])
    if num == test_num:
        ####do something ####
```